# Drools Decision Table List

Tags: drools

How can I make the list separated by comma formatted as "param1","param2","param3",.."paramN"?

Im using Decision Manager.

In Decision Table

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                  **Condition**                     |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|         **productDescription in ($param)**         |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|          FITI,FMSG,MSGC,RUNT,BEAU,LING-            |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

On Source

when
    productDescription in (FITI,FMSG,MSGC,RUNT,BEAU,LING)

I tried putting `"$param"` but returned 
productDescription in ("FITI,FMSG,MSGC,RUNT,BEAU,LING")

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to use *forall* but it doesn't compile. I also tried creating function which converts the parameter. **( function changeParam (String strParam){ List<String> lstParam = strParam.split(","); return lstParam;)** then used the condition **productDescription in changeParam("$param")** yet had a compilation error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is the function **MemberOf**. This will match your value to the array of values then will tag true if both fields are equal.